# New variable based on conditional arithmetic by group

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, plyr

I have a data.frame `df` where I want to create a new variable that is the proportion of another by group.  That is for each `Species` `ID` `Plot` `Sub` paring I'd like to find the proportion of `Area` by `Type`. If `Type` = 0, then `PropArea` == 1, if `Type` does not equal 0 (i.e. 1 or 2), then, for example, `PropArea` = `Area` (Type 1) / `Area` (Type 0). An sample data.frame is below. I know how to do this with if statements in excel, but was hoping to find a way to do this within `r`.

```
df <- structure(list(Species = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BFGR", "RNNN"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = c(201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 
    219L, 219L, 219L, 220L, 220L), Plot = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Sub = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L), Type = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), Area = c(0.78, 
    0.445, 0.023, 0.015, 0.79, 0.235, 1.29, 1.29, 2.555, 1.065, 
    1.365, 1.365, 2.678, 1.305), PropArea = c(1, 0.570512821, 
    1, 0.652173913, 1, 0.297468354, 1, 1, 1, 0.416829746, 1, 
    1, 1, 0.487303958)), .Names = c("Species", "ID", "Plot", 
"Sub", "Type", "Area", "PropArea"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

## A more complete data set    
 df_more <- structure(list(Species = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ACRU", "DIVI", 
"LIST", "LITU", "PEPA", "QULA"), class = "factor"), ID = c(205L, 
205L, 205L, 205L, 205L, 205L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 
219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 
219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 
219L, 219L, 221L, 221L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 
227L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 
228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 
228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 
229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L
), Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), Sub = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L), Type = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L), Area = c(5.67, 3.24, 
6.65, 4.26, 10.24, 1.31, 1.12, 1.23, 1.23, 0.88, 0.86, 0.86, 
0.11, 1.36, 1.36, 1.17, 2.33, 2.33, 1.15, 1.15, 1.23, 1.23, 1.27, 
1.27, 0.97, 0.97, 1.39, 1.39, 1.07, 1.07, 1.49, 1.49, 1.33, 1.33, 
2.35, 2.35, 1.8, 1.8, 7.5, 7.42, 6.35, 6.82, 0.37, 0.48, 8.67, 
8.57, 5.47, 5.66, 2.35, 2.42, 11.99, 12.8, 6.18, 6.19, 2.56, 
2.71, 25.77, 25.6, 16.01, 16.56, 3.36, 3.35, 1.08, 0.12, 5.34, 
5.34, 6.15, 6.15, 6.93, 6.93, 8.91, 8.91, 10.91, 10.91, 2.31, 
1.21, 3.2, 2.42, 2.41, 2.41, 2.32, 2.32, 2.48, 2.48, 0.7, 2.89, 
2.89, 1.27, 3.66, 3.66, 0.75, 8, 8, 8.85, 8.85, 11.22, 11.22, 
5.08, 2.96, 0.22, 5, 3.01, 0.92, 6.94, 3.88, 4.48, 1.18, 9.03, 
4.19, 0.5, 9.97)), .Names = c("Species", "ID", "Plot", "Sub", 
"Type", "Area"), row.names = c(NA, 111L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're OK with your data.frame being resorted, this should work:

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df_more, .(Species, ID, Plot, Sub), function(groupdf) {
  denominator <- groupdf[groupdf$Type==0,"Area"]
  if(length(denominator) == 0) denominator <- groupdf[groupdf$Type==1,"Area"]
  transform(groupdf, PropArea=Area/denominator)
})
```

And if you want to keep the same ordering, add these lines:

```
df1 <- df2[match(
  interaction(df[c("Species", "ID", "Plot", "Sub", "Type")]), 
  interaction(df2[c("Species", "ID", "Plot", "Sub", "Type")])),]
```

Comment: this works great on the subset of data above, however, I get the following error when used on the full data set `Error in data.frame(list(Species = c(2L, 2L), ID = c(229L, 229L), Plot = c(1L ,:arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0` I'll include the full data set above. Any suggestions? –

Comment: Looks like you have combos of Species,ID,Plot,Sub for which there is no Type 0. (to see this, add `if(length(groupdf[groupdf$Type==0,"Area"]) == 0) { print(groupdf) ; stop("didn't find a type 0 in this group") }` to the start of the ddply function argument). What do you want to do when there is no Type==0 in a group?

Comment: thanks, if there is not Type == 0, Then Type == 1, should be used instead, however, I can change this manually, as there are not very many.

Comment: That works. Or you could try the edited version above, which switches the denominator to Type==1 if there is no Type==0.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee alternation of `0`s with `1`s and `2`s like in your example, you could use `ifelse`:

```
df$PropArea <- ifelse(df$Type == 0, 1, df$Area / c(1, df$Area[-nrow(df)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicates in the df_more dataset. 
E.g. DIVI/22/1/2/0 is having an area of both 7.50 and 7.42. 
This will lead to errors.